# Python Method not in object error

Tags: python, object, methods

Im working on writing a method for an object and I keep getting the following error:'MagicCardSet' object has no attribute 'get_uncommon_colors'. All of my other methods work except this one so im kind of confused! Thanks!

Object that creates the Magic Card Set:

```
from collections import Counter

class MagicCardSet(object):


    def __init__(self, DeckDict):
        self.cardlist = [MagicCard(eachCard) for eachCard in DeckDict["cards"]]


    def get_card_list(self):
        Card_name_list=[]
        for newCard in self.cardlist:
            Card_name_list.append(newCard.get_name())
        return(Card_name_list)


    def get_card_color(self):
        color_list=[]
        for newCard in self.cardlist:
            color_list.append(newCard.get_colors())
        return(color_list)   


    def get_card_rarity(self):
        rarity_list=[]
        for newCard in self.cardlist:
            rarity_list.append(newCard.get_rarity())
        return(rarity_list)


    def get_rarest_card(self):

        card_rarities = Counter(card.rarity for card in self.cardlist if card.rarity !="Basic Land")
        rarity = min(card_rarities, key=lambda card: card_rarities[card])  # Effectively an argmin
        card_names=[card.get_name() for card in self.cardlist if card.rarity == rarity]
        card_colors=[card.get_colors() for card in self.cardlist if card.rarity == rarity]
        return (list(zip(card_names,card_colors)))


    def get_uncommon_colors(self):
        uncommon_list=[]
        for newCard in self.cardlist:
            if newCard.get_rarity()=="Uncommon":
                uncommon_list.append(newCard.get_colors())
        return(uncommon_list)
```

call:

```
DTK_Set=MagicCardSet(DTK_information)

DTK_Set.get_uncommon_colors()
```

Opening and storing JSON file

```
import json
with open('DTK.json',encoding="utf-8") as data_file:
    DTK_information = json.loads(data_file.read())
```

Whats in the JSON file:

```
{
    "name" : "Sen Triplets",
    "manaCost" : "{2}{W}{U}{B}",
    "cmc" : 5,
    "colors" : ["White", "Blue", "Black"],

    "type" : "Legendary Artifact Creature — Human Wizard",
    "supertypes" : ["Legendary"],
    "types" : ["Artifact", "Creature"],
    "subtypes" : ["Human", "Wizard"],

    "rarity" : "Mythic Rare",
}

Trace Error (Hopefully this helps a little more):

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-2c1a44dc0874> in <module>()
----> 1 DTK_Set.get_uncommon_colors()

AttributeError: 'MagicCardSet' object has no attribute 'get_uncommon_colors'
```

Comment: How are you making the method call?

Comment: Can you show us the line of code which raises this error. I mean, you only show us your class definition, but where is the instance of this class ?

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: 1. You don't show us how you create the object and call the method 2. please stick to PEP8 and keep the naming conventions (i.e. use capital case in the beginning of a name only for classes - not with variables/fields/methods) not following this simple principle makes your code more difficult to read.

Comment: I have updated it to include my call

Comment: And what's `DTK_information` ? please help us help you - it's harder to do it when we can't repro the issue!

Comment: I have updated my code showing what DTK_Information. All of my other methods in this class work except for get_uncommon_colors

Comment: It should work to me. I suspect that you have another definition of `MagicCardSet` "somewhere", which does not possess the method `get_uncommon_colors`. Where "somewhere" means between the definition you show us, and the instantiation/call.

Comment: No you have not since we have no idea what's in that file!

Comment: Please read [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is there an indentation error such that `get_uncommon_colors` isn't actually defined in the class, but as a function instead?

Comment: I just tried recreating it from scratch and it still seems to produce the error. Hence why Im asking and no there are no other definitions of MagicCardSet. This is the only definition.

Comment: Do you do the call from the same file as the one that contains the class definition ?

Comment: Im fairly sure since my other calls (DTK_Set.get_rarest_card()) and (list(zip(DTK_Set.get_card_list(),DTK_Set.get_card_color(),DTK_Set.get_card_rarity()))) work perfectly fine

Comment: Also i am doing the call from the same file. Im using DTK_Set for all of my calls which houses the JSON information

Comment: Show us the complete, exact error message, including stack trace.

Comment: Actually, we all should have started by asking you that :) @user2357112 is right.

Comment: There it has been added above :)

Comment: Clearly there is something you are not showing us, or you are showing it wrong. The code you posted, as it is, should run correctly.

Comment: I have another method but it isnt affecting this error since everything else runs fine. Im not showing anything wrong. I copied and pasted it right from my IDE to here

Comment: The traceback indicates you aren't running code from a file, but apparently entered directly into an iPython session.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again (the iPython interpreter I mean) ?  Just to be sure the issue is not linked to an old `import`.